# The meaning of "asterisk type asterisk" in C : *(volatile int *) foo

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have tried looking around but was not able to find an answer for this. I found something explaining when we use a double asterisk, **, however, I am not sure whether this applied to my case.

I have come across embedded systems code which looks a bit foreign to me :

```
port0 = *(volatile int *)(0x1C002100)
```

what this operation is doing is that it reads the GPIO port whose address is `0x1C002100`. However what is the deal with all those asterisks ?

I would have written this something like :

```
port0 = *0x1C002100
```

Are they doing some type of pointer type casting and hence we use 2 asterisks ? That would be my best guess. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Grab a book on C!!!!!

Comment: If that code really uses standard integer types like `int`, it is really bad code and tells something (not positive) about the quality of the code. Correct would be using fixed width types, e.g. `uint16_`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the expression, it first convert a integer constant to a pointer, then it deference that pointer, which will yield a integer. It is essentially the same as:

```
int *p = (volatile int *)(0x1C002100);
int n = *p;
port0 = n;
```

The first `*` denotes the pointer type, the second is a dereference operator.

However second line is invalid C code, since you cannot dereference a integer.

```
port0 = *0x1C002100;
```